# Why in my unity project the chasing part is not working?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Could someone please maybe download and see my project? It is very simple, but not working as in the tutorial.

In my project, I set `IsTrigger` to true in either the `ThirdPersonController` or the `AIThirdPersonController` for one of the characters. This makes the character fall down from the Plane.

I also changed one of the characters to be tagged as `Player` and changed the state from `PATROL` to `CHASE` but that changed nothing. The other player never chases/follows the player I am controlling and moving around.

Why are the players falling down when I set `IsTrigger` to true in my project?

I see in the video that the instructor is using a Maze Plane. Is that a package I should import in the Assets or is it already somewhere in the Assets? I just added regular Plane for now because I could not find a Maze Plane.

Here is a link for my project from my OneDrive. The file name is Demo `AI.rar`:

[Project in OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtV2OUzEcRzrlmv6Iwd2jSzx3nUM)

Here is a link for the video tutorial I am attempting to follow. It is supposes to be simple I suppose:

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s67AYDD3j1E)

Here is the `BasicAi` class I'm using in my project, the same script from the tutorial video:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class BasicAi : MonoBehaviour {

    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public ThirdPersonCharacter character;

    public enum State {

        PATROL,
        CHASE
    }

    public State state;
    private bool alive;

    // Variables for patrolling
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    private int waypointInd = 0;
    public float patrolSpeed = 0.5f;


    // Variable for chasing
    public float chaseSpeed = 1f;
    public GameObject target;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
        character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();

        agent.updatePosition = true;
        agent.updateRotation = false;

        state = BasicAi.State.PATROL;

        alive = true;

        StartCoroutine ("FSM");

    }

    IEnumerator FSM()
    {
        while (alive)
        {
            switch (state)
            {

            case State.PATROL:
                Patrol ();
                break;
            case State.CHASE:
                Chase ();
                break;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void Patrol()
    {
        agent.speed = patrolSpeed;

        if (Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, waypoints [waypointInd].transform.position) >= 2) {

            agent.SetDestination (waypoints [waypointInd].transform.position);
            character.Move (agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
        } else if (Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, waypoints [waypointInd].transform.position) <= 2) {
            waypointInd += 1;
            if (waypointInd > waypoints.Length) {
                waypointInd = 0;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            character.Move (Vector3.zero, false, false);
        }
    }

    void Chase()
    {
        agent.speed = chaseSpeed;
        agent.SetDestination (target.transform.position);
        character.Move (agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.tag == "Player") 
        {
            state = BasicAi.State.CHASE;
            target = coll.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't post more then one link yet so i'm adding here another link to my project in megafileupload http://www.megafileupload.com/nYky/Demo_AI.rar

Comment: I didn't download the archives but if you are using the IsTrigger() to handle collision you'll go through objects.

Answer (score 0):

Once a collider is a trigger it no longer collides with objects, your best bet is to place a child object that has a collider and setting that to the trigger, this way the original collider will still collide with your ground.

As for your other question how are you referencing your third person character, are you dragging it from the scene into the inspector, and you also have to bake your navmesh into your scene. I haven't looked at your project as that would take a lot of time, but maybe go through the tutorial again and see how they reference the character. With the inbuilt characters you normally have to access the namespace first.